# How to concatenate char and string / How to make char to string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 20

void main()
{
   int i, j;
   char *str1, *str2, *str3, *str_mid;
   bool **lcs1, **lcs2;
   int len1, len2, len3, len_mid;
   char *ch = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 3);


   str1     = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE); //applicatian
   str2     = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE); //apiasn
   str3     = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE); //apun
   str_mid  = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_SIZE); //apn

   str_mid = "";

   scanf("%s", str1);
   scanf("%s", str2);
   scanf("%s", str3);

   len1 = strlen(str1);
   len2 = strlen(str2);
   len3 = strlen(str3);

   //str2, str3 ->str_mid (lcs1)
   lcs1 = (bool**)malloc(sizeof(bool*)*(len3 + 1));
   for (i = 0; i < len3 + 1; i++)
      lcs1[i] = (bool*)malloc(sizeof(bool)*(len2 + 1));

   for (i = 0; i < len3 + 1; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < len2 + 1; j++)
         lcs1[i][j] = false;

   for (i = 1; i < len3 + 1; i++)
      for (j = 1; j < len2 + 1; j++)
         if (str3[i-1] == str2[j-1])
            lcs1[i][j] = true;

   for (i = 1; i < len3 + 1; i++)
   {
      for (j = 1; j < len2 + 1; j++)
         if (lcs1[i][j])
         {
            //<--- error
            ch = str3[i - 1];
            strcat(str_mid, ch);
            //--->
            break;
      }
   }

   //printf("%s", str_mid);
   //str_mid, str1 (lcs2)

}
```

In <--- error ---> part,
I want to concatenation **str3[i-1]** and **str_mid** but, **str3[i-1]** is character type.
So make temporary string is **ch** and do *concatenate*.
But, the access error is occurred.
*How to make char to string* or, *how to concatenate char and string?*

Comment: Strings in higher-level languages are an abstraction of buffers - which can be immutable, fixed-size, preallocated, or expanding (all with or without an in-channel sentinel value, typically `\0` aka "null-terminated string"). C does not define its own string-type, though most libraries use fixed-size buffers. You will need to take care of this by yourself.

Comment: OT: `sizeof(char)` is `1`be definition.

Comment: OT^2: Do not cast malloc and friends in C, its just useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So long as `MAX_SIZE` is large enough that `str_mid` will be able to hold the extra character, you can use `strcat()` and a compound literal (for C99 or later):

```
strcat(str_mid, (char[2]){ str3[i - 1], '\0' });
```

Note that in your code, `str3[i - 1]` is a `char`, while you have declared `ch` as a pointer to `char`.

Comment: This assumes `ch` is a `char` which by the OP's code it isn't.

Comment: @alk-- thanks. I had not noticed that OP had declared `ch` as a pointer to `char`.

Comment: Although this approach is unnecessarily (call to `strcat()`) expensive, it still is a nice example for the use of a compound literal: 1+

Comment: @alk-- thanks. I prefer your solution, but OP was trying to use `strcat()`, so I thought I would go that direction. Plus, compound literals are neat :)

Answer (score 1):

> How to concatenate char and string

There is *no* need to call any library function at all, nor to dynamically allocate any memory.

Assuming `str_mid` is large enough just do:

```
{
  size_t tmp_len = strlen(str_mid);
  str_mid[tmp_len] = str3[i - 1];
  str_mid[tmp_len + 1] = '\0';
}
```

---

To still have the feeling to use a function you might want to wrap the above code into a macro like this:

```
#define STRCATCHAR(s, c) \
do { \
  assert(s != NULL); \
  size_t tmp_len = strlen(s); \
  (s)[tmp_len] = (c); \
  (s)[tmp_len + 1] = '\0'; \
} while (0)
```

and use it like this:

```
STRCATCHAR(str_mid, str3[i - 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate char and string (first char, then string) do:

```
const char* conc_char_string(const char ch, const char* str, int len) {
    const char* out = malloc(len + 2); /* 1 char from ch, len chars from str, and zero character, totally len+2 */
    out[0] = ch; /* copy the character */
    strcpy(out+1, str); /* copy the string */
    return out;
}
```

Here `len` should be `strlen(str)`

Comment: length values should be typed as `size_t`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `str_mid = "";` assigns the address of costant string `""` to pointer `str_mid`, which will cause **segmentfault** later. Use `str_mid[0] = '\0';` instead.

In statement `ch = str3[i - 1];`, you are assigning `char` to `char pointer`, which will cause **segmentfault**.

If all you want is simply appending a character to the string, you can keep track of length of string, like this:

```
len_mid = strlen(str_mid);
for (i = 1; i < len3 + 1; i++)
{
  for (j = 1; j < len2 + 1; j++)
     if (lcs1[i][j])
     {

        str_mid[len_mid++] = str3[i - 1];
        str_mid[len_mid] = '\0';
        break;
     }
}
```

Comment: "*which will cause segmentfault.*" not necessarily, no.

Comment: @alk, cast another  type to pointer and dereference the pointer later almost always leads to segmentfault.

Comment: @smilingwang-- undefined behavior will not necessarily be a seg fault.

Comment: @alk, which one is undefined behavior?

Comment: @smilingwang-- `ch = str3[i - 1];` won't even compile with gcc, since `ch` is a pointer and `str3[i - 1]` is a `char`. The way I read the Standard, the attempt to modify the string literal pointed to by `str_mid` is a constraint violation: "An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand." (ISO/IEC 2011 6.5.16/2). While not explicitly called out as undefined behavior here, it seems like a fair interpretation.

Comment: @DavidBowling, in my host, when compiling the code, the compiler generate the message `warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`; when running the program, a segmentfault occurs, all are what I expect.  Here is my environment: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609.

Comment: @DavidBowling, `ch = str3[i - 1];`doesn't modify the string literal, it just assign a character to pointer, resulting an invalid address; modifying occurs in the statement `strcat(str_mid, ch);`.

Comment: @You are right that it is a warning, not an error: I forgot to remove a line that I had introduced to OP's code before testing. Now, the assignment that you mention is still a constraint violation (ISO/IEC 2011 6.5.16.1/1), which says that if the left operand is a pointer, then the right operand must be a pointer. But, this assignment does not cause a segfault on my machine. It is undefined behavior. As is the attempt to modify the string literal with `strcat()` or by other means. That is undefined behavior, but _does_ cause a segfault on my machine.

Comment: @smilingwang-- if I simply change `str_mid = ""` to `str_mid[0] = '\0'`, and use `strcat(str_mid, (char [2]){ch, '\0'};`, the program "works", despite all of the warnings and issues. But it is relying on undefined behavior. It is the attempt to change the string literal that is causing my segfault.

Answer (score -1):

First rule of the C-club, create your own string buffer, second rule of the C-club create your own string buffer.
Each programmer has it's own string buffer. Minimal requirement is :

```
 #define STRINGSTRTSZ 256
 typedef struct string
 {
     char *str;
     size_t n;
     size_t buf_sz;

  }String,*pString;

  pString new_string()
  {
      pString res;
      res=malloc(sizeof(String)); ///i leave to you the error handling
      res->bus_sz=STRINGSTRSZ;
      res->n=0;
      res->str=malloc(res->bus_sz); 
  }
  char*concatbase(pString *string,char*s,size_t len)
  {
      if(len+1>=string->buf_sz-string->n)
      {
           res->buf_sz+=len+res->buf_sz; 
           char *tmp=realloc(string->str,res->buf_sz);
            if(tmp)
               string->str=tmp;
            else
              ...
      }
     memcpy(string->str+string->n,s,len);
     string->n+=len;
     *(string->str+string->n)='\0';
     return string->str;  
  }

  #define concatNllPtr(string,nllptr) concatbase(string,nllptr,strlen(nllptr))
  #define concatString(string,str2) concatbase(string,(str2)->str,(str2)->n)
```

End so on...

Comment: I changed strcpy() to memcpy() so you can concatenate also substrings;

Comment: Take care to not miss to `0`-terminate the result then.

Comment: "*Each programmer has it's own string buffer.*" I doubt this.

Comment: Yeap you are right not "each programmer" has his own string buffer, but "each Programmer" has is own string buffer. With "P" capitol. So just to nominate the lasts API with I deal "RedisModule_String", "varlena" of postgres, "wxString" from wxWidgets, LPTSTR from Windows... and so on. It is so proper of the language that nobody is going to explain their scope, and the functions are called exactly "concat_buffer" "concat_string" and so on...

Comment: At least `LPTSTR` is nothing more then just a pointer. No buffers there!